# Typescript cannot exclude "*.d.ts" files

Tags: typescript, tsc, tsconfig

If you generate output in same folder as input you can get the error

> TS5055: cannot write file 'file.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.

This is (off course) because tsc reads also the *.d.ts files. But when I add the option `"exclude": [ "**/*.d.ts" ] "` to tsconfig.json the error does not go away. That means that tsc does actually not exclude the files I've specified.

Has anybody encountered the same issue and isn't it a bug in tsc?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? If yes single click the .d.ts file in Solution Explorer and in the Properties Window change `Build action` from `TypeScriptBuild` to `None`.

Comment: Thanks @Misaz. I use Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio Code. My issues was only concerning running the TS compiler from the command line relying on the settings in `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 0):

Found out, that this is no longer an issue in TSC 2.4, so must have been fixed since 1.8. Just to let anyone else know.